# Android PullToRefreshListview shake when soft keyboard pops up

Tags: android

I hava a PullToRefreshListview and a EditText,PullToRefreshListview in the middle, EditText at the bottom，When the soft keyboard pops up, shake occur list。The issues was caused by PullToRefreshListview itself, because it is a remote library I have no idea what is the reason and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact the author of the library and ask the author. Nobody else is likely to be able to help you debug behavior in this library. In the future, when citing problems in libraries, provide a link to the library. In this case, there are many pull-to-refresh libraries, and nobody knows which one you are using.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am using http://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/.

Comment: You will notice that the project's README contains the following prose in very large bold letters: "PLEASE NOTE, THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER BEING MAINTAINED". I suggest that you move to [some other pull-to-refresh implementation](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/78).

Comment: @CommonsWare Providing me those infos deosn\`t even help me solve my problem. Put change the lib aside, focus on the question itself please. I read the source code and I know it was cause by the onsizechange method from here https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshBase.java#L844. But I didn`t figure out how to fix it yet.